# JS regular expression to validate alphanumeric values

Tags: javascript

looking for a regular expression in javascript which can test a string that has 4 alphabets and 7 Numeric values exp "ABCD1234567"

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Seems like you're looking for a copy-paste solution

Comment: tried this /^(?=([a-zA-Z]){4}[0-9]{7}*$)/ but no luck, not able to understand expression format

Answer (score 3):

#### Some regex basic of your requirements

`^` means start
`$` means end
`[A-Z]` means from A to Z in uppercase
`[a-z]` means from a to z in lowercase
`\d` or `[0-9]` means from 0 to 9
`{4}` means repeat times of the expression (eg. `4` here)

so for your case, this regex should works

```js
/^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7}$/
```

#### Case insensitive

If both uppercase & lowercase need to be supported, you can write

```js
/^[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{7}$/
```

or add a case insensitive regex flag `i`

```js
/^[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{7}$/i
```

### Reference

You can read about Regex document [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

You can also reach out [regex101](https://regex101.com/) to learn more about regex and test it online.